What Exactly is the difference between "Public Class" vs "Struct" (In cpp)
I wonder, if class's members are public then they behave same as struct. But there should be some difference in between them, right. When should we use public class vs struct?

"The class uses reference type. A struct is a value type." - that sounds like C#, there is no such distinction in C++. class and struct only differ by default access specifier.

I know this, The class uses reference type. A struct is a value type. -- This is totally wrong.  As mentioned this sounds like you are using C# or similar language to determine how C++ works.  In general, do not use another computer language to figure out how C++ works, or use another computer language as a model in writing C++ code.

@PaulMcKenzie, okay got it. But can u please differentiate this, when can I use "public class" vs when to use struct?

You can use either class or struct.  As mentioned already both in the first comment and the duplicate, this: struct foo { int x; }; is no different than class foo {public: int x;};.  The only difference is that members are by default, private in a class, but they are public in a struct, and the default inheritance is public for struct and private for class.  Otherwise there is no other difference.  A struct can have member function, virtual functions, constructors, destructor, etc. no different than a class.

Also, if you were to go on a C++ interview, and the interviewer asks you the difference between a class and struct, your initial answer would disqualify you immediately.  I don't know in today's job market, but a lot of C# programmers would exaggerate their C++ experience, and the question about the difference between struct and class was the classical question used to weed out and disqualify those persons who didn't tell the truth on their resume about the C++ experience they had.
